# What is the quickest way to kill all sessions from a specified user in Oracle?

Tags: windows, oracle

What is the quickest way to kill all sessions from a specified user in Oracle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do it in a `PL/SQL` loop. Make sure to test it with just logging the parameters before actually calling `kill session`.

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (
    SELECT s.sid,
           s.serial#
    FROM   v$session s
    WHERE  s.username = 'your_user_name'
  )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session ''' || 
                      c.sid || ',' || c.serial# || '''';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

See similar [question on asktom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6633782199868).

Answer (score 3):

Another approach that could run faster overall is to generate orakill commands and execute them in a DOS window:

```
SELECT 'orakill '||d.name||' '||spid
  FROM v$session s JOIN v$process p ON addr=paddr
                   JOIN v$database d ON (1=1)
WHERE s.username = 'THE_USER';
```

Orakill does not wait for session transactions to complete, so the kill is very fast.

Whatever your solution turns out to be, be careful!

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be aware of is that killing a session in Oracle does not necessarily stop the user's session (and associated processes) from consuming resources.  So a runaway query may continue to run away, consuming resources like CPU and I/O and holding locks, until it checks back in with Oracle's process monitor (pmon) process/thread.

Assuming one's running Oracle on a Unix system in "dedicated connection" mode, one can join v$session and v$process on v$session.paddr = v$process.addr to find all the sessions and processes for a given user's connections, and use the UNIX `kill` commmand with `SIGKILL` to kill the underlying server processes for the user's sessions.  pmon will then clean up the failed session, rolling back any transactions and releasing any locks.

This is definitely a big-hammer approach when the approach Peter Lang's previously pointed out isn't killing the user's sessions aggressively enough.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)  The Oracle server we develop on runs on Windows.  I've added a tag to the question.

Answer (score 0):

alter system checkpoint;
shutdown abort
startup restrict
shutdown immediate

:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very light improvement of Peter Lang's answer that I find easier to use. It is interactive and asks for the username:

```
PROMPT Entrer the username to kill;
DEFINE username = &1
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (
    SELECT s.sid,
           s.serial#
    FROM   v$session s
    WHERE  s.username = '&&username'
  )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session ''' || 
                      c.sid || ',' || c.serial# || '''';
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```